# Getting RuntimeError: "In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly" when I've already included them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

Inside a controller I've tried to run this code for when users that are already logged in stumble across the sign up page

```
def index
  if current_user
    redirect_to homebase_url #should provide url to home for logged in users
  end
end
```

I've done what the rails error message said and have added: `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to the containing controller class. Still getting this error though. Definitely do not want to hardcode URLs into there for legacy purposes. Thanks

Comment: Typically, you shouldn't need need to include url_helpers in a Rails controller. Two questions:  

(1) Are you sure the error is being thrown by the line calling `redirect_to homebase_url`? If it's being thrown somewhere else (such as within a template), you may have to include the url_helpers somewhere else, like the ApplicationHelper.  
  
(2) Would you be able to show a full stack trace along with more of the full controller class?

Comment: I had added the `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to an initializer and somehow that was screwing everything up. Figured it out right after I left the bounty. I guess if anything I wouldn't mind knowing why that caused that..

Comment: Could you post the entire controller class and the initializer, there might be an issue with including the UrlHelpers in the initializer before routes are loaded.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to help.

Comment: Please post the full error with backtrace - it isn't coming from that line unless that line is surrounded by unusual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` declaration, it's not needed unless it's in something like a helper. Routes are included in controllers by default. Including it in a model or controller/initializer (routes are loaded before initializers) is against MVC architecture and might cause unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `homebase_path` instead of `homebase_url`

For example when looking at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903124/getting-runtimeerror-in-order-to-use-url-for-you-must-include-routing-helper/42048113#42048113`

```
console.log(window.location.pathname) // => "/questions/41903124/getting-r..."
console.log(window.location.host) // => "stackoverflow.com"
```

**path** is the stuff after the domain name(host).

a complete **URL**(in your case `homebase_url`) requires both a `host` and a path. In development its a bit awkward to get a host because its a different value in production than it is in development.